# iPhone - UIButton with non resized image inside

Tags: iphone, image, interface-builder, uibutton

I have a UIButton with a "custom" type, with an "image" property that gets its image from resources. The image is smaller than the button. I cannot achieve into Interface Builder to keep the original size of the image while scaling the button's dimensions as I want.

How may I have a button of any size into IB, keeping the original image size, aligning it on center, left right, bottom, inot the button... ? Isn't it possible without putting a UIImageView on it ?

Comment: Post some code. Are you talking about the button background image or the button image? Not sure exactly what behavior you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @XJones : There's no code, I'm talking about the "image" property  into Interface Builder.

Comment: UIImageView has only more animation functions than the UIImage. Nothing what can help in your case i think

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do and what's not working. Button images do not scale as the button size changes. Button background images do scale.

Comment: @XJones : That's simple. I have a UIButton in Interface Builder, I have set the "image" property (not the background one) with a resource image (into the dropdown list), and this image scales to the button scale.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure that the `contentHorizontalAlignment` and `contentVerticalAlignment` properties of your button are not set to `UIControlHorizontalAlignmentFill` and `UIControlVerticalAlignmentFill` respectively. Those values will scale the button image to fill the button frame. Any other value will align the image appropriately.

Comment: @Oliver, I'll have to trust you on that. There are no other properties I know of that would cause the image property of a UIButton to scale based on the size of the button. The only way I can reproduce your issue is by setting the control alignment options to fill. I am doing this all in IB, I assume you are as well based on your comments.

Comment: Stupid problem. In fact, my image resolution was too large, and when setting the view mode to anything else than fit/fill, the image wasn't truncated but filled the button. I thought that my image was small enought, and this behaviour kept me in the mistake. So after reducing the image size, no more problem, and your answer was right.

Comment: glad you figured it out. we all make mistakes like that.

Answer (score 4):

Use image foreground to put non-resizable image elements, found in a post on stackoverflow but forget where it is.

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-10,0,0);

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This is good but you can also set the button's image insets in Interface Builder ;-)

Comment: nah, that's too easy